# Creating two triangle using php

Tags: php

Someone please help me to create a two triangle patter using PHP. I'm already code but the output didn't as expected below.
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubCPf.png)

My code:

```
function generatePattern($num) {
      for ($id1 = 0; $id1 <= $num; $id1 = $id1 + 1) {
         for ($id2 = $num; $id2 >= $id1; $id2 = $id2 - 1) {
            print(' ');
         }
         for ($id3 = 1; $id3 <= $id1; $id3 = $id3 + 1) {
            if ($id3 % 4 == 3) {
               echo "o";
            } else if ($id3 % 2 == 1) {
               echo "x";
            } else {
               echo " ";
            }
         }
         echo "\n";
      }
for ($id1 = 0; $id1 <= $num-1; $id1 = $id1 + 1) {
         echo str_repeat(' ', $num - 1);
         for($id3 = $num-1; $id3 >= $id1; $id3 = $id3 - 1){
            if ($id3 % 4 == 3) {
               echo "o";
            } else if ($id3 % 2 == 1) {
               if ($id1 % 4 == 3) {
                  echo "o";
               } else if ($id1 % 2 == 0) {
                  echo " ";
               } else if ($id1 % 2 == 1) {
                  echo "x";
               } else {
                  echo "x";
               }
            } else if ($id3 == $id1){
               echo "x";
            } else {
               echo " ";
            }
         }
         echo "\n";
      }
   }

   generatePattern(4);
```

And my current output like this (the bottom triangle still messed up)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cchpU.png)

Comment: Debugging is a priceless skill in the world of programming. Familiarize yourself with debugging techniques in [PHP](https://stackify.com/php-debugging-guide/). It might seem a little overwhelming at first, but start with the basic things, like getting the output of variable content. That way you can track how variable values change throughout your iterations and help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: This is a nice beginner's (but thorough) guide to debugging in php. https://stackify.com/php-debugging-guide/

Comment: @El_Vanja yeah debugging is good for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Do the required changes for space between `o` and `x`

```
function generatePattern($num) {
    if($num % 2 == 0)
    {
        $num1 = $num + 1;
    }else{
        $num1 = $num;
        $num = $num - 1;
    }
    for ($id1 = 1; $id1 <= $num; $id1++) {
        
        for ($id2 = $num; $id2 >= $id1; $id2--) {
            print(' ');
        }
        for ($id3 = 1; $id3 <= $id1; $id3++) {
            if ($id3 % 4 == 3) {
                echo "o";
            } else if ($id3 % 2 == 1) {
                echo "x";
            } else {
                echo " ";
            }
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
    $str = str_repeat('x o ', ceil(($num1*2)/4));
    echo substr($str, 0, $num1*2);
    echo "\n";
    $j = $num;
    for($id1 = $num; $id1 >=1; $id1 = $id1 - 2)
    {
        for($id2 = 2; $id2 >= 1; $id2--)
        {
            if($j % 2 == 0)
            {
                $pattern = [' ', 'x', ' ', 'o',];
            }else{

                $pattern = [' ', 'o', ' ', 'x',];
            }
            echo str_repeat(' ', ($id2%2 == 0) ? $num: $num - 1);

            $design = implode('', $pattern);
            do{
                $design .= implode('', $pattern);
            }while(strlen($design) < $id1);
            echo substr($design, 0, $id1);
            echo "\n";
        }
        $j--;
    }
}

generatePattern(14);
```

Comment: sorry but the bottom triangle still wrong. You can see my attached image above for bottom triangle.

Comment: Yes I know... I was on it.  But had to leave incomplete

Comment: It would be very helpful to include an explanation of what was changed, where and why. This way, you don't levae people guessing and having to meticulously compare your code to the original from the question.

Comment: Please help me. I'm stuck on second triangle too.

Comment: @El_Vanja do you have any idea with this issue?